# undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass -- Can't figure out what this means

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When the user is logged in the home action redirects the user to new_status_update_path where they will see a form to submit a new status_update.

```
def home
 if user_signed_in?
  redirect_to new_status_update_path
 end 
end
```

Then the new action within the status_update_controller should simply pass in the status_update object to the views form so that it can be manipulated.

Status Update Controller:

```
def new
  @status_update = current_user.status_update.build if user_signed_in?
end
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
<%= form_for(@status_update) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :weight %>
  <%= f.text_field :weight %>

  <%= f.label :bf_pct %>
  <%= f.text_field :bf_pct %>

  <%= f.submit "Post", class:"btn btn-large btn-primary" %> 
<% end %>
```

Rendering error:

```
NoMethodError in StatusUpdatesController#new

 undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass

app/models/status_update.rb:36:in `default_values'
app/controllers/status_updates_controller.rb:10:in `new'
```

status_update.rb

```
class StatusUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user

   after_initialize :default_values

   attr_accessible :current_weight,
               :current_bf_pct,
               :current_lbm,
               :current_fat_weight,
               :change_in_weight,
               :change_in_bf_pct,
               :change_in_lbm,
               :change_in_fat_weight,
               :total_weight_change,
               :total_bf_pct_change,
               :total_lbm_change,
               :total_fat_change,
               :previous_weight,
               :previous_bf_pct,
               :previous_lbm,
               :previous_fat_weight,
               :created_at

   validates :user_id, presence: true
   validates :current_bf_pct, presence: true,
                          numericality: true,
                          length: { minimum: 2, maximum:5 }  
   validates :current_weight, presence: true,
                          numericality: true,
                          length: { minimum: 2, maximum:5 } 
   validates :current_lbm, presence: true
   validates :current_fat_weight, presence: true                   

   def default_values      
     if self.current_bf_pct >= 0.5
       self.current_bf_pct /= 100
        if self.current_bf_pct <= 0.04
          self.current_fb_pct *= 100
        end 
     end
     self.current_fat_weight = self.current_weight * self.current_bf_pct
     self.current_lbm = self.current_weight - self.current_fat_weight
   end  

   def previous_status_update
     previous_status_update = user.status_update.where( "created_at < ? ", self.created_at ).first   
     if previous_status_update == nil
       return self
     else
       previous_status_update
     end
   end 

    default_scope order: 'status_updates.created_at DESC'

 end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show what your `status_update.rb` file looks like? Particularly the area around line 36?

Comment: Your exception tells you were it was raised (`app/models/status_update.rb:36:in `default_values'`). But you don't provide that method

Comment: Sure thing! I added it at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue might be with your usage of `after_initialize`. If I remember correctly, `after_initialize` is called after a new object is created. At that point, all of the attributes on your object would be nil, and thus, you wouldn't be able to use a comparison like `>=`.

**Edit:**

You can try setting the values using the `||=` idiom, which will set the default value on an attribute only if it's nil. So something like `self.current_bf_pct ||= 0.5` would set the `current_bf_pct` to 0.5 if the attribute is nil, otherwise it would use its current value.

In other words, it looks like you're trying to compare the values of attributes that haven't been set yet.

Comment: Thanks! I created one more method to help with setting the values before hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass
```

It means that you are trying to use the `>=` operator on an instance of the `nil` object inside of the status_update file, line 36. According to the error.

Check to make sure you are calling Status Updates Controller properly and that the data is flowing as you expect it to.